# How to set a value in a sequence?

Tags: racket, sequence

I trying to write a simple tic tac toe game in Racket and am having trouble figuring out how to set a value in a sequence.

I have the follow 2d sequence of characters:

```
(define playing-board '((#\- #\- #\-)
                        (#\- #\- #\-)
                        (#\- #\- #\-)))
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
(let ([row (sequence-ref playing-board y)])
  (sequence-set? row x #\O)
)
```

Now that think about it, even if that did work, it would only alter `row` and `playing-board`.

Answer (score 1):

Lists cannot be mutated like that in Racket, so you have to choose a data structure that can be mutated such as a [vector](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/vectors.html). For example:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.4.0.15.
-> (define playing-board (vector (vector #\- #\- #\-)
                                 (vector #\- #\- #\-)
                                 (vector #\- #\- #\-)))
-> (define x 0)
-> (define y 1)
-> (let ([row (vector-ref playing-board y)])
     (vector-set! row x #\O))
-> playing-board
'#(#(#\- #\- #\-) #(#\O #\- #\-) #(#\- #\- #\-))
```

Alternatively, you can instead return a new list instead of trying to mutate it in place.

Answer (score 1):

Asumu's answer is of course entirely correct.

For this problem, though, I think I might be inclined to use an immutable
hash from lists of numbers to cell values.  This gives you a handy functional
update and probably matches your intuition better as well:

```
#lang racket

(define my-board
  (for/hash ([row (in-range 3)]
             [col (in-range 3)])
    (values (list row col) #\-)))

(hash-ref my-board (list 1 1)) ;; -> #\-
(define updated-board (hash-set my-board (list 1 1) #\X))
(hash-ref updated-board (list 1 1)) ;; -> #\X
```